# how to turn array key into property so I can access it as property

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object

I have an array of settings and I would like to access it like :

`$settings->type`

instead of :

`$settings['type']`

inside of blade. I prefer the first version since its more elegant.

here is my array:

```
array:5 [▼
  "enable" => "true"
  "type" => "native"
  "must_be_registered" => "true"
  "allow_nested" => "true"
  "nested_level" => "5"
]
```

I tried turning it into collection

```
Collection {#382 ▼
  #items: array:5 [▼
    "enable" => "true"
    "type" => "native"
    "must_be_registered" => "true"
    "allow_nested" => "true"
    "nested_level" => "5"
  ]
}
```

but that did not help really, I still could not do `$settings->type` inside blade, anyone knows how I can do this?

```
Property [type] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

Comment: Try casting to `object`?

Comment: I do not know how to do that, is there a function for that?

Comment: actually quick google search helped, thanks alot! :)

Comment: first `json_encode` the object and then `json_decode` it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well try this work around:

```
$array=[
  "enable" => "true",
  "type" => "native",
  "must_be_registered" => "true",
  "allow_nested" => "true",
  "nested_level" => "5"
];

$settings=json_decode(json_encode($array));

echo $settings->type;
```

Or

```
$settings=(Object)$array;

echo $settings->type;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use (object)array like this,

```
<?php

$array=[
  "enable" => "true",
  "type" => "native",
  "must_be_registered" => "true",
  "allow_nested" => "true",
  "nested_level" => "5"
];

$settings=(object)$array;

echo $settings->type;
```

[demo here](https://eval.in/771549).